# Python: How to create a separate module for the GUI class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-module

This code is working fine. MyApp is the class doing all the work and MyGUI is the user interface showing and requesting data from MyApp.

```
class MyGUI(): # displays results from MyApp and sends request to MyApp (e.g. fetch prices new prices)

    def __init__(self):
        print("GUI running")

    def user_request_price(self,ticker):        
        self.req_price(ticker)

    # methods I request from MyApp 
    def req_price(self,ticker): 
        app.get_price(ticker)

    # methods I receive from MyApp
    def print_price(self,val,price):
        print (val,":",price)    

class MyApp(): # does a lot of stuff, e.g. fetch prices from a server

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.gui = MyGUI() # start gui

    # methods called by GUI
    def get_price(self, ticker):
        if ticker == "MSFT": price = 20.23
        self.output_price(ticker,price)

    # methods sent to GUI
    def output_price(self,ticker,price):
        self.gui.print_price(ticker,price)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = MyApp()
    app.gui.user_request_price("MSFT")
```

Now I want to put the GUI into a separate module so creating a module file gui.py and import that in the MyApp file:

```
from gui import *
```

and that's it. Where I struggle: how does gui.py look like and how can MyGUI() access MyApp methods? Is it wise to do this separation? Any other suggestions for structuring?

Comment: Yea it's okay to seperate them both. And it's easy to import your backend methods via `from <module_name> import all`

Answer (score 1):

The gui.py file would just be

```
class MyGUI(): # displays results from MyApp and sends request to MyApp (e.g. fetch prices new prices)

def __init__(self):
    print("GUI running")

def user_request_price(self,ticker):        
    self.req_price(ticker)

# methods I request from MyApp 
def req_price(self,ticker): 
    app.get_price(ticker)

# methods I receive from MyApp
def print_price(self,val,price):
    print (val,":",price)
```

Add the import to the top of myapp.py and everything should work fine.

I try and Seperate out my code into seperate files if it makes sense.  It makes reading things much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

in your `gui.py`

```
from myapp import MyApp

class MyGUI(): # displays results from MyApp and sends request to MyApp (e.g. fetch prices new prices)

    app = MyApp()

    def __init__(self):
        print("GUI running")

    def user_request_price(self,ticker):        
        self.req_price(ticker)

    # methods I request from MyApp 
    def req_price(self,ticker): 
        app.get_price(ticker)

    # methods I receive from MyApp
    def print_price(self,val,price):
        print (val,":",price)
```

And in your `myapp.py` (Notice the first line), And make sure both the files are in same directory or else you must change your import relatively.

```
from gui import MyGUI

class MyApp(): # does a lot of stuff, e.g. fetch prices from a server

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.gui = MyGUI() # start gui

    # methods called by GUI
    def get_price(self, ticker):
        if ticker == "MSFT": price = 20.23
        self.output_price(ticker,price)

    # methods sent to GUI
    def output_price(self,ticker,price):
        self.gui.print_price(ticker,price)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = MyApp()
    app.gui.user_request_price("MSFT")
```

Comment: "gui.py", line 11
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: I've update the code but however your example seems to have lot of interleaving between two classes. You must however always try to attain one-way dependency between classes. So when you write code try to write all the backend methods in one class and import that entire class into your frontend file. And do not bring your frontend methods into your backend class.

Comment: Thanks but still does not work. 
> ImportError: cannot import name 'MyGUI'
So at least pyhton 3.6. forbids mutual cross referencing.
Your comment makes a good point but that's just the nature if you want to strictly seperate GUI from core. GUI sends messages to core and receives messages from core. Very open for a generic approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this - seems to be the best approach to have a clear separation and communication between app and gui.

Gui:

```
import queue

def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.requests = queue.Queue()  # request queue for App
    self.start()

def queue_request(self,reqId,val):
    self.requests.put([reqId,val])
```

APP:

```
import threading
import queue

def checkGUIQueue(self):
    threading.Timer(1.0, self.checkGUIQueue).start() # check every 1 second                
    while not self.gui.requests.empty():
        (id,value) = self.gui.requests.get()
        ... process request ...
```